# How to take screenshot of entire activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot, android-screen-support

The following code works.However it only takes a screenshot of whatever items are in view to the user , if the app is running on a small screen and a textview is not being shown ( have to scroll up or down) , the screenshot will not show the textview. How do I take a screenshot of the entire activity regardless of the screensize?

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/groceryrun.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}


private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/groceryrun.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share This Deal With Your Friends!"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are taking screenshot of a `View` who is just a kid. go for the parent

```
Activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
```

now call your codes.

let me know if it works

Comment: I don't understand that code . getWindow is giving an error

Comment: what error? the Activity. there is `yourActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()`@ChadPrecilla